# post html as string through ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a tinymce wysiwyg and i want to post the html from it to my action method:

```
   $("#save").click(function () {
            var ed = tinymce.get('wysiwyg');
            var id = $("#destinationId").val();
            var PostContent = JSON.stringify({ 'content': ed.getContent(), 'destinationId' : id });
            console.log(PostContent);


            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("SaveDestinationContent", "Home")',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                cache: false,
                data: PostContent,
                success: function (data) {

                },
                error: function (xhr, error) {
                },
            });
```

I always get null in my action method that looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveDestinationContent(string content, string destinationId)
    {
        return Json("TRUE");
    }
```

i have tried to do this in a couple of different ways:

```
   $("#save").click(function () {
            var ed = tinymce.get('wysiwyg');
            var PostContent = ed.getContent();
            console.log(ed.getContent());
            var id = $("#destinationId").val();

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("SaveDestinationContent", "Home")',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                cache: false,
                data: {
                    content: PostContent.toString(), destinationId: id
                },
                success: function (data) {

                },
                error: function (xhr, error) {
                },
            });
```

but none of them work!

<---- EDIT ------>

I know it has to do with the serialization of the html because when i just add some random string and post that it works as expected!

Comment: are you reaching your success or error function ? Add a console.log('something') so you know...

Comment: Take a look at the request in your browser's dev console and look at the post body contents. If they look right, your problem may actually be in how you wired up the action method.

Comment: i do reach the controller method but the parameters is always null.